# Google Maps API Javascript. Cannot load the InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I've been trying to load an InfoWindow on the marker but I couldn't load it. I am trying to load the InfoWindow after the user clicks on the marker. Is the issue because I didn't define the eventListener in the intialize()? I tried doing it, but still it didn't work! Can anyone **help**?

The javascript code is:

```
var zwsid = "*My_API_Key*"; 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var mapObj;
var map_Estate;
function initialize() 
{
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var defaultLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5286416, -0.1015987); //defines location of the Map
  map_Estate =        // defines the properties of the map
  {  center: defaultLoc,
     zoom:16,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  }
  mapObj = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('mapArea'), map_Estate);  //creates a object to load in HTML file
}

function xml_to_string ( xml_node ) 
{
  var value1, marker;
    //document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "Entered addrMap";
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
      document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = " LATLNG is: "+ results[0].geometry.location+ " STATUS: " + status;
             mapObj.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                map: mapObj,
                                                position: results[0].geometry.location  });                 
    }  
    else 
    {   alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);  }
    });    
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
    {
        var infoProp = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "Value of the property is "});
        infoProp.open(mapObj, marker);
} );           

if (xml_node.xml)
value1 = xml_node.xml;
var xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer();
value1 =  xml_serializer.serializeToString(xml_node);  
document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML += "City: "+document.getElementById("city").value +
                                                 ",  State: "+document.getElementById("state").value+ ", Cost: "+value1+"<br></br>";
}

function displayResult () 
{
    if (request.readyState == 4) 
    {
    var xml = request.responseXML.documentElement;
    var value = xml.getElementsByTagName("zestimate")[0].getElementsByTagName("amount")[0];        
    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xml_to_string(value);
    xml_to_string(value);
}
}

function sendRequest () {
request.onreadystatechange = displayResult;
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
var zipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
request.open("GET","proxy.php?zws-id="+zwsid+"&address="+address+"&citystatezip="+city+"+"+state+"+"+zipcode);
request.withCredentials = "true";
request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Add a simple jsfiddle to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Pls update this fiddle with your html and xmlfile. Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/mmy15svu/

Comment: @bnz I've updated the jsfiddle file with the HTML. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is by using an Zillow API, I'm trying to extract the prices of the property. So, the xml file is connected with the API.

Comment: pls share the url of the updated fiddle

Comment: @bnz http://jsfiddle.net/mmy15svu/3/

Comment: @bnz I hope you get what I'm trying to do. I'm sorry for the sad design. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move the listener inside the if-statement, it will work.

Beside that i'd recommend to clean up and structure your code.

IF-Statement (JS)

```
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
      document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = " LATLNG is: "+ results[0].geometry.location+ " STATUS: " + status;
             mapObj.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                map: mapObj,
                                                position: results[0].geometry.location  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
    {
        var infoProp = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "Value of the property is "});
        infoProp.open(mapObj, marker);
} );         
    }
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/z1dx45rL/

Comment: can you tell me what does this mean:  `function xml_to_string( xml_node){  var value1;  if(xml_node.xml)  value1=xml_node.xml;  var xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer();  value1 = xml_serializeToString(xml_node);`

Comment: Some values are coming from an xml-file. Dont know if these are markers - or your other api (zillow). Can you share one of these xml files?

Comment: I don't have the xml files. I just have the API key!